I'm writing a DAX which doesn't show any error but it doesn't show any value when I use it
I want to know the no. of Onsite DNB on a particular date so I'm using the following DAX:
Onsite DNB HC (Present) = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Sample Data'),'Sample Data'[Revenue Status]="DNB", 'Sample Data'[Location]="Onsite",'Sample Data'[Date]=16-07-2024)

It does not show any error but when I use this, it doesn't show any value.
I tried removing the date filter and apply the date through filter option then it works fine but I want to filter the date in the formula only. How to do this?

You will need to provide the date like so DATE(yyyy, M, d).
Try:
Onsite DNB HC (Present) =
  CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('Sample Data'),
    'Sample Data'[Revenue Status] = "DNB",
    'Sample Data'[Location] = "Onsite",
    'Sample Data'[Date] = DATE(2024, 7, 16)
  )

As you have it now it is doing 16 minus 7 minus 2024.
